# Assigning an element of a swift array to a userdata parameter triggers didSet

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa, pointers, tooltip

I created the default Cocoa/Swift app. My AppDelegate class is below. I have hooked the view in the window to the `view` IBOutlet in the AppDelegate.

What I am trying to do is assign a element from an array to the userdata for a tooltip. The code executes and prints 'did set' three times. I would have thought it would only print 'did set' twice, but the third time is when addToolTipRect is called and I pass in the first element of the array as the userdata for the tooltip rect.

This seems strange to me and I was wondering if anyone knew how I could avoid this behavior. The behavior I was looking for is for didSet to only be called when myArray was assigned to perhaps a different array entirely. Perhaps didSet is not what I want to be using...and, if not, what should it be?

There is a simple test project demonstrating this behavior at:

https://github.com/ericgorr/tooltip_arrays

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var view:   NSView!

    var myArray         = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    {
        didSet
        {
            NSLog( "did set" )
        }
    }

    override func view(view: NSView, stringForToolTip tag: NSToolTipTag, point: NSPoint, userData data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> String
    {
        let pUserData = UnsafeMutablePointer<[String:AnyObject]>(data)
        let userData  = pUserData.memory

        return "hello"
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
    {
        self.myArray.append( [ "one" : "a" ] )
        self.myArray.append( [ "two" : "b" ] )

        view.addToolTipRect( NSMakeRect( 0, 0, 100, 100), owner: self, userData: &(myArray[0]) )
    }



    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `userData` parameter in `.addToolTipRect` is an **inout** parameter, meaning it accesses the element in read-write: even if the value isn't changed, the didSet is triggered as expected in this case.

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545

> When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
>   In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
>   When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

In this case, with `&`, even if the value in the array is not changed, the array is written to by the method.

Comment: Yes, that all makes sense. So, the question is what can I do about it? The number of tooltips I need is the same number of elements in the array and the number of elements in the array can change over the lifetime of the application. So, it is natural to store the information needed by the tooltip inside of an array and pass a pointer to an array element as the userdata for the tooltip. If my current implementation is not going to work, what is the recommended implementation for this kind of behavior? Create a different array that contains the tooltip information and does not have a didSet?

Comment: I'm not an expert about addToolTipRect but as far as I know, you're doing it right. I've read the documentation recently and that's what I would have done too. // If it doesn't work (or if the behaviour is not what you expect), we'll be there to fix it. ;)

Comment: Ok. I still need a solution. I guess the only one for now is to create a separate array with the tooltip information. The didSet on the primary array in the real case needs to do some actual work and having it triggered on assigning elements of that array by calling addToolTipRect is screwing things up badly. If you want to add a proposed solution to your answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: I still would have thought that didSet would only be called when myArray changed to a different array, not when elements of that array were changed.

Comment: didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored, even if it's the same value. And any write access to the variable will trigger the didSet. // As for a solution, since addToolTipRect uses an inout parameter, I don't see how we could avoid didSet to be triggered; so indeed didSet in this array maybe isn't what you want in your case (but I have no alternative to suggest at the moment, sorry).